# KIVY Text within label

Tags: label, kivy

Trying to place text within a Rectangle. I even tried solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741068/python-kivy-add-text-inside-rectangle). 
I want the text to be within Rectangle. This should holds good even if I change window size please. When I add_widget Actor I still want to continue pos_hint and size_hint format. Any idea please..

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
Window.size = (800, 600)

kv = '''
<Actor>:
    canvas:
        PushMatrix
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,0,.8
        Rectangle:
            id: _rect_
            size: self.width, self.height/12
            pos: 0, 11 * (self.height / 12)
        Line:
            points: self.width/2, 11 * self.height/12, self.width/2, 0
            width:2
        PopMatrix
    Label:
        id: _actr_lbl
        text: 'Hello World'
        markup: True
        color: 0,0,0,1
        pos: 0, 11 * self.height/12
        halign: 'center'
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)

class Actor(Scatter):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) :
        super(Actor, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = RelativeLayout()
        layout.add_widget(Actor(pos_hint = {'center_x':0.5, 'top':0.95}, size_hint = (0.2, 1)))
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you want by adjusting your `kv` for the `Label` slightly:

```
Label:
    id: _actr_lbl
    text: 'Hello World'
    markup: True
    color: 0,0,0,1
    size_hint: None, None
    size: root.width, root.height/12
    pos: 0, 11 * root.height/12
    halign: 'center'
```

Adding `size_hint: None, None` allows the `size` to be effective. And referencing `root` for `size` and `pos` info keeps the `Label` sized and positioned correctly.